# cyvcf2 not working in Ubuntu 18.04 / Python 3.7.5

Tags: python

I have installed cyvcf2 using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip -y
sudo apt install libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev -y
pip3 install cyvcf2
```

When I run:

```
cyvcf2 --help
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devuser/.local/bin/cyvcf2", line 7, in <module>
    from cyvcf2.__main__ import cli
  File "/home/devuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cyvcf2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .cyvcf2 import (VCF, Variant, Writer, r_ as r_unphased, par_relatedness,
ImportError: /home/devuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cyvcf2/cyvcf2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: SHA256
```

Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: Were there any errors/warnings/messages in the commands you listed? (apt update & installs)

Comment: No, while installing it worked OK.

Comment: `python3` should have already been installed, so that message should have occurred.. your system either isn't Ubuntu, or is non-standard so I cannot help (missing info)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

sudo apt-get -y install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev